# How configure Octavia in Openstack Kolla?

Tags: openstack, openvswitch, openstack-neutron

Im trying to deploy Octavia in Kolla Openstack, my global.yml is:

```
config_strategy: "COPY_ALWAYS"
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
kolla_install_type: "source"
kolla_internal_vip_address: "169.254.1.11"
network_interface: "eth0"
neutron_external_interface: "eth1"
neutron_plugin_agent: "openvswitch"
enable_neutron_provider_networks: "yes"
enable_haproxy: "yes"
enable_cinder: "yes"
enable_cinder_backend_lvm: "yes"
keystone_token_provider: 'fernet'
cinder_volume_group: "openstack_cinder"
nova_compute_virt_type: "kvm"
enable_octavia: "yes"
octavia_network_interface: "eth2"
```

I use a default/automatic configuration, keypair, network and flavor are created in service project. Then I create the amphora image for this project.

All this is indicated in the Openstack guide, but it doesn't work.

When I create a loadbalancer, the amphora is deployed but the loadbalancer is "Pending Create" status. I saw that the created network is vxlan, a tenant network, and I think that it should have external conectivity, I tried but didn't work.

I check the openvswitch configuration and don't see any difference deploying with or without Octavia.

Do I miss something? I don't know what to do at this point, I even tried the manual config but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the kolla part of this issue, but with the load balancer in PENDING_CREATE, the controller (worker) logs should show where it is retrying to take some action against your cloud and failing. It will retry for some time, then move to an ERROR status if the cloud issue is not resolved in time.

Without seeing the logs, my guess is kolla did not setup the lb-mgmt-net correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. Checking the log, the octavia-worker is trying to connect to amphora:

2021-01-26 09:05:09.130 19 WARNING octavia.amphorae.drivers.haproxy.rest_api_driver [-] Could not connect to instance. Retrying.: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='169.254.2.44', port=9443): Max retries exceeded with url: // (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f28a822e130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host'))

The lb-mgnt-network is tenant, so normally it won't be accessible.

Comment: Kolla should be setting up connectivity from the Octavia controller processes onto the lb-mgmt-net which is in the Octavia tenant. This is how the controllers and amphora communicate for management and metrics.

Comment: Hi, in my case, there was no connectivity to the tenant network from controller, I had to make it manually.

Comment: By default, Kolla-Ansible creates a VXLAN-based lb-mgmt-net to which the controllers have no direct connectivity. The Octavia installation guide shows how to establish such a connection via a NIC named o-hm0 - but it assumes the Linuxbridge mechanism driver. Kolla normally uses Openvswitch. Connecting controllers to an Openvswitch bridge is a difficult undertaking for mere mortals (to which I count myself).

Comment: Hello All, any luck in creating the bridge with open vSwitch on the controllers? I am stuck at this point which official kolla doc says as below. "If using a VLAN provider network, ensure that the traffic is also bridged to Open vSwitch on the controllers."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get it working with an external network - but for the tenant network it appears the solution is:

1. Setting `octavia_network_interface` will make kolla create that interface, so any name will do. When referencing other setups (ie. the devstack plugin) they name this `o-hm0`. So this is what I did.
2. Set `octavia_network_type` to `tenant` in `globals.yml`. Note this requires the host to have `dhclient` available, kolla didn't seem to install this for me.

I tested this on `stable/zed` and it appears to work for me.